# Find How many customers returned after 1year of inactivity,2year of inactivity etc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a transaction data frame as follows.

```
        customer_id order_date     product_id   value($)
             139    2015-07-08           A       0.174
             139    2015-06-08           B       1.236
             432    2017-08-09           E       0.205
             474    2019-08-27           A       0.374
             164    2022-05-08           D       0.278
```

How do I find how many customers returned after one year (365 days)  of inactivity, two years (730 days) of inactivity etc.?

Comment: use the datetime module, calculate timedelta

Comment: timdelta as @ArpitOmprakash said then you could groupby that column if you wanted/needed to

Comment: Can you guys write an answer with the codes?  My attempts were not successful.

Comment: It would be easier to do if you provided a [dataframe constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14627505)

Comment: if a customer had two periods of 1 year inactivity, then what should the output be? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Preparations:**

```py
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
inact_period = pd.Timedelta('365 days')
```

**Solution:**

```py
def f(ser, inact_period):
    ser = ser.sort_values()
    return (ser - ser.shift() > inact_period).any()
    
n = df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].agg(f, inact_period=inact_period).sum()
```

`n` is an integer - the result.

If one customer that has multiple inactivity periods should count multiple times, then you can replace `.any()` with `.sum()`.

**Example:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'order_date': pd.to_datetime(['2015', '2016', '2017', '2019', '2022'])})

   customer_id order_date
0          139 2015-01-01
1          139 2016-01-01
2          139 2017-01-01
3          139 2019-01-01
4          164 2022-01-01
```

**With `.sum()`:**

If I set `inact_period = pd.Timedelta('365 days')`, then `n == 2` (since 2016 is a leap year there are 366 days between 2016-01-01 and 2017-01-01).

If I set `inact_period = pd.Timedelta('366 days')`, then `n == 1`.

**With `.any()`:**

If I set `inact_period = pd.Timedelta('1 d')`, then `n == 1`.